# Java Calendar giving wrong value after parsing month string

Tags: java, date

I know that Java month begins from 0 and we have to add an offset of 1 to it,but when I use the following code which has a CST time zone,I get value for february month as 6.

I am trying to convert month to its equivalent calendar value such as 1 for January and 2 for Feb and so on.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").parse("FEB"));
    int monthInt = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    System.out.println(monthInt);
```

But when I run it in a machine with time zone as Indian Standard Time(IST-GMT +5.30) I get the expected value as 2.

What is wrong here?Do I need to include any locale to my calendar.I am getting totally meaningless values for months with the above code.

Comment: Ther is nothing worng in the code It should Print 2 .

Comment: But it isnt..thats the issue in a machine with a different time zone.

Comment: That's the whole point of the question, @RakeshKR

Comment: Try passing a locale object to `new SimpleDateFormat`, it's parsing is locale sensitive. It might not parse "FEB" as "february".

Comment: @GreedyCoder I think SO...

Comment: You could try extra lines: 
`Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").parse("FEB")`
`System.out.println(d)`
Just to see what Date you get

Comment: I tried passing Locale.US,but still the same result.

Comment: @NickJ : It gives the output as Sun Feb 01 00:00:00 CST 1970

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should instantiate your `Calendar` with appropriate locales:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"),Locale.US);
```

Comment: The locale and time zone did the trick.Actually it was CST.Thanks

Comment: I am skeptical. If getting value for February month as 6 should be a locale problem, you would need to run your code on a JVM with a locale setting where the 6th month has an abbreviation like `FEB`. On my Java 8 no such locale exists.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Month.JANUARY.getValue()
```

> 1

## Wrong class

You are trying to represent a month using a class that represents a moment. Square peg, round hole.

> But when I run it in a machine with time zone as Indian Standard Time(IST-GMT +5.30) I get the expected value as 2.

Again, this occurs because you used the wrong class, a class that represents a moment in the context of a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

> I know that Java month begins from 0

Again, you are using the wrong class. This crazy numbering is one of many reasons why the date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java were supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310 and built into Java 8 and later. Do not use the legacy classes.

## `Month`

The appropriate class for a month is [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html). This modern *java.time* class has sane numbering, unlike the legacy date-time classes that you should avoid.

> convert month to its equivalent calendar value such as 1 for January

Use the [`Month.JANUARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#JANUARY) enum object.  As for its number, 1-12 for January-December.

```
int monthNumber = Month.JANUARY.getValue() ;
```

> 1

But I suggest you avoid representing a month by a mere integer number. Instead, use `Month` enum objects throughout your codebase. This makes your code more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code), ensures [valid values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation), and provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

Use this:

```
public void runMonthlyReport( Month month ) { … }
```

…instead of this:

```
public void runMonthlyReport( int monthNumber ) { … }
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).